# dropdown list in javascript & php (symfony 1.4)

Tags: javascript, php, symfony-1.4

Here's my problem :

In my default dropdown list I have the value "1". My problem is that when I select in my dropdown list the value "2", my page reloads correctly but in the view it gives me the value "1" in my list.

code javascript :

```
   function filter(){
var id = document.getElementById('liste-biens').options[document.getElementById('liste-biens').selectedIndex].value;
    var url = "<?php echo html_entity_decode($url); ?>"+id;
window.location =url;
```

}

Code php :

```
<select id="liste-biens" onChange="javascript:filter();"><?php
        foreach($dataLevels as $level){
            $lib_immeuble_value = $level->getAttribute('lib_immeuble');
            $codimm_immeuble_value = $level->getAttribute('cod_immeuble');
            $codimmcop_immeuble_value = $level->getAttribute('cod_imm_cop');

            if ($libimm->getDisplay()){
                ?><option  <?php
                if($current_code_imm == $level->getAttribute('cod_imm_cop')){ echo 'selected="selected"'; }
                ?>value="<?php echo $level->getAttribute('cod_imm_cop');?>"><?php
                    echo $level->getAttribute('lib_immeuble') . ' - ' . 
                        $level->getAttribute('adr1_immeuble') . ' -  ' . 
                        __("Immeuble") . ' ' . str_pad(html_entity_decode($level->getAttribute('cod_immeuble')),5,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT) . '/' .
                        __("Client") . ' ' .str_pad(html_entity_decode($level->getAttribute('codcli_immeuble')),7,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT) . '/' . 
                        __("Copropriétaire") . ' ' . str_pad(html_entity_decode($level->getAttribute('codcop_immeuble')),7,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);

                ?></option><?php
            }
        }
    ?></select><?php
```

Comment: Why is this labeled as "Symfony"? I don't see any Sf related problem here. Also the way you construct your select list is not very nice (and a bit unreadable too). You shouldn't mix your template with code that does any logic. And as for your question - you should check if you properly set the value of `$current_code_imm`, this seems to be the problem.

Comment: Beacause i use symfony 1.4 as a framwork, my javascript is fine and my current_code_imm is also fine. He contain the value of my field symfony declared in my app.yml. i also call the variable  $current_code_imm in my indexSucess of symfony with an include_partiel of the url like this : include_partial(xxxxxxmy block symfony, array('vBlock' => vListeBlock, 'url' => 'index.php?option=com_compte&view=compte&Itemid=83&codimm=', '$current_code_imm' => $_GET['cod_imm'])); ))
Someone can help me please

Comment: Just because you use Sf in your project it doesn't mean you should be tagging the questions wit it. Your question is not symfony related. You said that your problem is that option 2 is not being selected on the list after page refresh. You use the variable `$current_code_imm` to determine which position on the list should be selected. Hence I think that your var `$current_code_imm` does not contain the value you expected.

Comment: In the url you use `codimm` but when you read the value you check the value of `cod_imm` so there's something wrong here. Also you shouldn't use the `$` sign when naming the variable while passing to the partial: `'current_code_imm' => $_GET['codimm']`.

Comment: Anyhow - if you do use Symfony I would recommend having a look at the Form classes. Symfony offers you a very nice and clean way to handle your forms.

Comment: You are right Michal :D i just found it ! the problem was that the current_code_imm get the wrong value wich is cod_imm. the right one is 'current_code_imm' => $_GET['codimm']. Thank you very much :)